# SDL DXA Java 1.4 - Missing dd4t dependencies

Tags: dxa, java, dxa-1.4

I'm trying to run the branch develop for the project web-application-java in github using the 2013sp1 profile. However, when installing the app with maven all the dxa dependencies can not be found

> The following artifacts could not be resolved: 
>   org.dd4t:dd4t-api:jar:2.0.5-DXA, org.dd4t:dd4t-core:jar:2.0.5-DXA,
>   org.dd4t:dd4t-databind:jar:2.0.5-DXA,
>   org.dd4t:dd4t-providers:jar:2013sp1:2.0.5-DXA:  Could not find
>   artifact org.dd4t:dd4t-api:jar:2.0.5-DXA in central
>   (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)

I think there's a problem with the **DXA** classifier which is not defined in the repo.

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/dd4t/dd4t-core/2.0.5/

Is it alright? Or I'm missing any extra configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this in your pom.xml (for version 1.4)

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>dxa-github-repo</id>
        <url>https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/release/1.4/local-project-repo/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```